# Obscure Xcode build error: "The file “myapp-SBPartialInfo.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."

Tags: ios, build, xcode6

I'm getting the following error toward the end of the build:

error: could not read data from '/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-ftieubjjfkuwyrhhleghfevbhxuu/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/myapp-SBPartialInfo.plist': The file “myapp-SBPartialInfo.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

The only thing I can think of is that it is a result of having aborted a build an hour or so ago.

I have cleaned, quit Xcode, rebooted my computer - none of the easy fixes are working. I've checked the other build directories (Debug-iphonesimulator and Release-iphoneos), and neither of those directories contain the file either. But both the simulator and the archive are building correctly.

Xcode bugs are the worst.

Comment: I see a comment in another site mentioning it could relate to recently added Segues. Esp if you use popovers and the anchor is illegal for some reason. Just says to check recently added segues.

Comment: Yes, I saw that too. But my code has been stable for a while (this is a two-year-old project), and I haven't changed my Storyboard in months. The other thread was discussing a similar error in a Storyboard intermediate build file. This one seems linked to my info.plist.

Comment: The other thing I noticed in another build was an attribute on the build of --output-partial-info-plist. It used an identical file name to yours except the file was Main-SBPartialInfo.plist and not myapp--SBPartialInfo.plist. Have you looked at the full build output to see where it is generating and using that file? Could be a permissions issue.

Comment: Possibly, but it builds just fine for the simulator as well as for archive. I have looked at the directory and it does not look any different from the other intermediate-build directories (corresponding to simulator or release).

Comment: I figured it out. The iphonesimulator build directory did contain the missing file, so I copied it over to the iphoneos build directory and it worked. Freakin' Xcode... Thanks for encouraging me to have another look at my directories.

Comment: Glad you are back in action. Happy coding...

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel you've just saved my day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I heard back from Apple Support.

Something was wrong with one of the generated files. Here are the steps to fix it:

1) Quit Xcode.

2) Open Finder and select Go > Go to Folder...

3) Delete the DerivedData folder

4) Open Xcode.

5) Clean your project

6) Build

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed that. There seems to be a bug in Xcode 6 (and it hasn't been resolved with the latest, as far as I can tell). Just repeat as necessary. It's annoying, but at least there's a workaround.

Comment: Yeah, I now just have a tab open to that folder for quick access :)
It only started happening when I updated my xibs. Hopefully Apple fixes this error soon.

Comment: we are in Xcode 7 beta and the bug is still there. It is amazing how a company launches a tool like xcode.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that somehow the Run action in my scheme showed my app's name without the ".app" extension.  Editing the scheme and picking AppName.app fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I resolved this by setting the Deployment Target to iOS 9.0 from iOS 8.0, as I had a UIStackView, which is not supported before iOS 9.0