# Archiveing Unity project from Xcode error "The file "Unity-Project.ipa" couldn't be opened because there is no such file"

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity Project which I want to export for adHoc, I am getting this error at the end of the export

"The file "Unity-Project.ipa" couldn't be opened because there is no such file"

Have tried re-naming the project.  Creating a new scheme.  Re-exported the Unity project for Xcode.  Cleaned the project, restarted Xcode, and other bits without any success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obscure Xcode build error: "The file “myapp-SBPartialInfo.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087895/obscure-xcode-build-error-the-file-myapp-sbpartialinfo-plist-couldn-t-be-ope)

Comment: The proposed duplicate doesn't seem to have any relationship to the question.